# MySQL - group by new column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to group by a new columns here - one three counts.
It's a scenario where I want to see open, closed and plan orders for each date.

At the moment, with the code below I'm getting the results however I want to have a column with Main Date and count for each dates.

The results I am getting are as follows:

```
+------------+----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
| Closed     | ClosedNo | Open       | OpenNo | Plan       | PlanNo |
+------------+----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
| NULL       |        0 | NULL       |      0 | 2018-10-22 |      3 |
| NULL       |        0 | NULL       |      0 | 2018-10-23 |      1 |
| NULL       |        0 | NULL       |      0 | 2018-10-24 |      1 |
| NULL       |        0 | NULL       |      0 | 2018-10-25 |      1 |
| NULL       |        0 | 2018-10-25 |      1 | NULL       |      0 |
| NULL       |        0 | 2018-10-26 |      1 | NULL       |      0 |
| NULL       |        0 | 2018-10-27 |      2 | NULL       |      0 |
| 2018-10-22 |        3 | NULL       |      0 | NULL       |      0 |
| 2018-10-23 |        1 | NULL       |      0 | NULL       |      0 |
| 2018-10-25 |        1 | NULL       |      0 | NULL       |      0 |
+------------+----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
```

The desired results are:

```
Date        ClosedNo    OpenNo  PlanNo
22/10/2018  3                   3
23/10/2018  1                   1
24/10/2018                      1
25/10/2018  1           1       1
26/10/2018              1   
27/10/2018              2
```

This is a code I use.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(Closed DATE, 
Open DATE,
Plan DATE);


insert into Orders values ("2018-10-23",NULL,NULL);    
insert into Orders values ("2018-10-22",NULL,NULL);    
insert into Orders values ("2018-10-22",NULL,NULL);    
insert into Orders values ("2018-10-22",NULL,NULL);    
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-23");
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-22");
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-22");
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-22");
insert into Orders values (NULL,"2018-10-26",NULL);    
insert into Orders values (NULL,"2018-10-27",NULL);    
insert into Orders values (NULL,"2018-10-27",NULL); 
insert into Orders values (NULL,"2018-10-25",NULL); 
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-24");
insert into Orders values ("2018-10-25",NULL,NULL);    
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-25");

SELECT 
Closed
, COUNT(Closed) AS 'ClosedNo'
,Open
, COUNT(Open) AS 'OpenNo'
,Plan 
, COUNT(Plan) AS 'PlanNo'
FROM 
Orders
GROUP BY
Closed, Open, Plan;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, `Open` and `Date` are [Keyword(s) in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O). You should really name your column to something else; or you will have to use backticks around it.
- We can use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to get the `Date`. It will consider the first non-null value.
- Using [`Count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) aggregation function, we can count the non-null rows, for a `Date` group.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(Closed, `Open`, Plan) AS `Date`, 
  COUNT(Closed) AS ClosedNo, 
  COUNT(`Open`) AS OpenNo, 
  COUNT(Plan) AS PlanNo 
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY `Date`
```

**RESULT**

```
| Date       | ClosedNo | OpenNo | PlanNo |
| ---------- | -------- | ------ | ------ |
| 2018-10-22 | 3        | 0      | 3      |
| 2018-10-23 | 1        | 0      | 1      |
| 2018-10-24 | 0        | 0      | 1      |
| 2018-10-25 | 1        | 1      | 1      |
| 2018-10-26 | 0        | 1      | 0      |
| 2018-10-27 | 0        | 2      | 0      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oHNiGEN6davmBqdPykgqa3/1)

Comment: Thank you! That is all I needed.

Comment: @Kalenji happy to help :) Nicely framed question btw +1